# Detecting memory leak in Python

Tags: python, performance, unix, memory, memory-leaks

I have a python module running as a service. Is there a way to detect the memory leak on the process running?

So far most of the tools I have seen online such as [muppy](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html) either just gives the memory usage on all the running processes (I have several python processes) or requires me to run the python code as part of the tool (which I am unable to do since my code is running as service).

Any idea how to at least capture memory usage or may be even detect memory leak from there?

Comment: Have you seen http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html

Comment: If you can't modify the source why are you looking into this at all? You wont be able to fix them anyways (and, if this isn't true, then you *can* modify the source to use those tools).

Answer (score 0):

I made a small script that gets the memory usage of a script, however, it only runs on osx (for sure) and linux (more than likely). This was just a way to get the memory internally, not externally, so you'll need to implement a few lines to get your other scripts' PID and detect that scripts' memory usage.

```
#imports
import resource
import time

#variables
loops = 1
#gets initial memory usage
memusg = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
#captures initial memory usage
cptrdmemusg = memusg

#loop
while loops == 1:
    #waits for a time, making cpu utilitization non-existant
    time.sleep(300)
    #gets new memory usage
    memusg = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    #detects memory leak. '*3' can be any number.
    if memusg == cptrdmemusg*3:
        print "Memory Leak Detected!"
        print "Memory Usage"+memusg
```